# Concurrency issue with WCF and nHibernate

Tags: c#, wcf, nhibernate

we have a WCF webservice handling some business entities. ORM is nhibernate 4.0.4, .NET 4.0.
We are using an IDispatchMessageInspector to open a session and a transaction in AfterReceiveRequest, context class is wcf_operation:

```
public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
{
    if (!CurrentSessionContext.HasBind(this.factory))
    {
        this.log.Log.Debug("Creating NH Session");
        var session = this.factory.OpenSession();
        session.FlushMode = FlushMode.Never;
        session.BeginTransaction();
        CurrentSessionContext.Bind(session);
    }

    return null;
}
```

The transaction is committed and the session is closed in BeforeSendReply.
This is working as long as only one call at a time deals with a specific entity.

If two concurrent webservice try to update the same entity, I get an nhibernate exception

> NHibernate.HibernateException: Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions

As I understand that two updates collide on the database level, I do not understand the problem nhibernate has here. 
From my understanding, the two sessions of the two calls should be independent of each other; am I missing something here? A configuration maybe?

As said, I see the problem the database has; nevertheless, I would expect an exception claiming something about conccurent update or so.
Since the traffic on the webservice grows, I fear that I have a general problem with my session handling.

Comment: Can you show us the `BeforeSendReply` method?

Answer (score 1):

This problem is not a concurrency issue. The issue is that you are using Sessions in a way they are not designed for.

When an entity object is loaded from the database, it *belongs* to the session that loaded it. The session holds an internal map of all of the objects it has loaded. It you try and make this session interact with an object loaded by a different session, it will recognise that the object is not in its internal map and throw an exception.

Keep in mind that a session follows the [UnitOfWork](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html) design pattern. They are meant to be short lived. You create a session, read from the database, make changes, and then discard the session along with all of the in-memory objects.

NHibernate does provide a way to detach an object from a session and then attach it to a different session, but this approach would be  fraught with danger in a concurrent environment. Instead, I suggest you modify your design so that the shared object is not an nHibernate entity but some kind of key reference to the entity, which can allow any separate session to reload it if needed.

If you feel that some objects really should stay in memory for the lifetime of your WCF service, you can make use of the nHibernate second-level cache. [This blog entry](http://www.gitshah.com/2012/03/nhibernate-and-caching-part-2.html) explains the second-level cache quite well.

Comment: These objects are not in memory for the lifetime of the service, they are per call. As described, a new session is created per wcf call. My problem occurs when two webservice calls (having an own session each) try to manipulate the same entity (which should be different entities in memory, in my opinion, since they come from different sessions)

Comment: To make it a bit clearer, an example: lets say we have an entity "Person" with aname, an id and a collection of addresses. Now two users try to update the same person, lets say with id 1. I have two concurrent calls to my webservice, both for person with id 1. For each call, a new session is created (see above), the person is fetched from db, updates are made, person should be saved. But then the exception mentioned above is thrown.

Comment: @Maroni - Is this action spread out amonst multiple WCF calls? Or is this entire fetch-update-save action all done as one call?